Curve integral $\int_C (e^{\sin x}-x^2y) dx + e^{y^2} dy$
I have some troubles solving the following curve integral over C which is the unitcircle $x^2+y^2=1$ paced once in a positive joint:
$$
\int_C (e^{\sin x}-x^2y) dx + e^{y^2} dy.
$$
I'm using Green's theorem and polar coordinates which gives $x=r \cos \phi, y=r \sin \phi, P=e^{\sin x}-x^2y, Q=e^{y^2}$:
$$
\iint_D \bigg( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \bigg) dxdy = \iint_D 0--x^2 dxdy = \iint_D x^2 dxdy
$$
$$
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2 \phi d\phi \int_0^1 r^3 dr = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1+\cos 2\phi}{2} d\phi = \frac{1}{8} \bigg[ \phi + \frac{\sin 2\phi}{2} \bigg]_0^{\pi/2} \neq \frac{\pi}{4} = solution.
$$
Any suggestions on what I have missed? I think C is not closed(?) and I should introduce two new curves along the X and Y axis, but I don't know how to integrate $e^{\sin x}$.
Thanks.
Sincerely, TS

Is it $2\pi$ instead of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Is it? I thought "paced once in a positive joint" meant $0<\phi<\pi/2$..

Indeed, the domain of integration should be a closed curve in order to apply Green's theorem.

@TerribleStudent I guess ``paced on in a positive joint" means the path is actually the whole circle arc, but in a positvely oriented direction.

Do you have the correct answer? Assuming that $C$ is one lap along the unit circle in positive direction I get the integral $\iint_{\text{unit disc}}x^2,dx,dy=\pi/2.$

@md2perpe the solution is $\pi/4$

@AngaeMT I see, but then I obtain the correct answer if I let $0<\phi<2\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$. Thanks.

I realized that I made an error when calculating the double integral.
